# codeigniter: how to insert multiple array value into mysql database in one time?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

i have an array like this

```
array(3) { 
  ["address"] => array(3) { 
     [0] => string(9) "Address 1" 
     [1] => string(9) "Address 2" 
     [2] => string(9) "Address 3" 
  } 
  ["number"] => array(3) { 
     [0] => string(3) "123" 
     [1] => string(3) "456" 
     [2] => string(3) "789" 
  } 
  ["state"] => string(3) "usa" 
}
```

I want to insert the array data into the my database table. so, I hope I have an array of data to be entered into a database like this

```
id |  address  |  number  |  state
----------------------------------
1  |  Address 1 |   123    |   usa
2  |  Address 2 |   456    |   usa
3  |  Address 3 |   789    |   usa
```

how to insert array data into database table like that in one time? my array is **dynamically**, the number of arrays can be changed any time.

Comment: 1) write insert using mysql's extended syntax. 2) use a loop and insert single records until you've gone through the array.

Comment: @MarcB can you explain how to do the looping?

Comment: is this array  the result from $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use existing array

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($arr["address"]); $i++)
    $this->db->insert('TABLE', 
      array( "address" =>$arr["address"][$i],
             "number" => $arr["number"][$i],
             "state" =>$arr["state"])");
```

Or  create new array and do one batch insert

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($arr["address"]); $i++)
   $batch[] = array( "address" =>$arr["address"][$i],
             "number" => $arr["number"][$i],
             "state" =>$arr["state"])");
$this->db->insert_batch('TABLE', $batch);
```

Answer (score -1):

only 1 way:
loop

like this:

```
$arr=array(1=>5,2=>8,3=>14);//a simple array for example
    for($i=0;$i<$ARRAYMAX;$i++){
        mysql_query("insert into Table1(x) values($arr[$i])");
    }
```

---

```
    $arr =array(3) { 
  ["address"] => array(3) { 
     [0] => string(9) "Address 1" 
     [1] => string(9) "Address 2" 
     [2] => string(9) "Address 3" 
  } 
  ["number"] => array(3) { 
     [0] => string(3) "123" 
     [1] => string(3) "456" 
     [2] => string(3) "789" 
  } 
  ["state"] => string(3) "usa" 
} 


for($i=0;$i<$ARRAYMAX;$i++){

    mysql_query("insert into TABLE(address,number,state)
    values($arr[0][$i],$arr[1][$i],$arr[2][$i])");
}
```

try this,i hope this code helps you

Comment: can you give an explanation of my case? I am confused as to how the implementation of the data array looping to insert it into the database table @EsmailJamshidiasl